# Having a vertical background for menus where content moves out of container

Tags: css, css-float

I want to know the best way to achieve the below image in CSS+HTML.

I'm having difficulty explaining in words what I want, so I guess a picture would make it more clear:

[image]

While the second and third parts are doable. I'm curious to know the best way to achieve the first one (Blue menu). If i split my page into three parts (based on the menus), in the case of blue, my div items must float out of the horizontal width of the menu, but within the vertical.

Thoughts wise ones?

Comment: Thoughts are only wise if you have ability code yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpdqA/1/show/)

You can see i have used `position:relative` on parent and `position:absolute` on child to make it flow out of that `li` element.

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    width:906px;
    height:600px;
}
li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:300px;
    height:600px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.selected {
    background:yellow;
}
.div {
    position:absolute;
    left:-150px;
    width:600px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:2;
}
#div-1 {
    top:30px;
}
#div-2 {
    top:140px;
}
#div-3 {
    top:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by position: absolute.

```
.blueDiv{
    position:relative; 
}
.innerDiv{
    position:absolute; 
    top: (your choice);
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(innerDivSize / 2);
}
```

If you don't have the width of the elements inside ... you can try to push them to the left and right by:

```
.innerDiv{
    position:absolute; 
    top: (your choice);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

But that will work only if the parent element is not on the very left or very right of the page.